# displaying Java output in a web browser

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following java code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;   
import java.sql.DriverManager;   
import java.sql.ResultSet;   
import java.sql.Statement;


public class License {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {   

        Connection connection = null;   
        ResultSet resultSet = null;   
        Statement statement = null;   

        try {   
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");   
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/license_tracker/usage.db3");   
            statement = connection.createStatement(); 
            System.out.println("Connection Successful!!!!");
            String query = "SELECT  USR.id,USR.name, ST.license FROM users USR, status ST, upd_ate UD WHERE UD.upt_id = (select max(p2.upt_id) from upd_ate p2) AND ST.id = USR.id AND ST.upt_id = UD.upt_id ORDER BY ST.license,USR.name";

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);  

            while (resultSet.next()) { 

                System.out.printf("%8s   %-50s   %-7s%n",resultSet.getString("cymer_id"), resultSet.getString("name"), resultSet.getString("license"));   

            }   
        } catch (Exception e) {   
            e.printStackTrace();   
        } finally {   
            try {   
                resultSet.close();   
                statement.close();   
                connection.close();   
            } catch (Exception e) {   
                e.printStackTrace();   
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
```

I want to display the contents of the resultSet in a web browser, essentially IE9, in a tabular format. I've searched about this and I think there are two options to this, using JAVA applet or JSP. Since I have to run the code on the server should I use JSP?I'm not so familiar with JSP, so I would appreciate if someone can help me with that. I'm using Eclipse Indigo & have Tomcat ver 7.

I have a html code on the webpage layout. I wanna put the information in the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<head>


<!-- FORMAT OF THE BOXES //-->
<style type="text/css">

div.ex
{
width:360px;height:300px;
padding:10px;
border:5px solid gray;
margin:0px;
background-color:linen;}

    div.graph
{
width:800px;height:300px;
padding:10px;
border:5px solid gray;
margin:0px;
background-color:linen;}


</style>





</head>


<body>




<!--h1=> LOGO & h2=> Heading //-->




<h2 style="text-align:center;font-family:century schoolbook;color:black";><b>Pro/Engineer And Intralink License Logs</b></h2>



<!-- License summary bar //-->
<div id="content" style="background-color:mediumpurple;clear:both;text-align:center;"><big>License Summary</big></div>

<!-- TABLES //-->
<center>
<table cellspacing="5" border="0" cellpadding="0">



 <td><p><div class="ex"><center>DESIGNER LICENSES</center><br/></p></td>


 <td width="2" bgcolor=black><BR></td>
 <td>
 <p><div class="ex"><center>LEAD LICENSES</center><br/></p>
 </td>


 <td width="2" bgcolor=black><BR></td>
 <td>
 <p><div class="ex"><center>CABLING LICENSES</center><br/></p>
 </td>


 <td width="2" bgcolor=black><BR></td>
 <td>
 <p><div class="ex"><center>LICENSES</center><br/></p>
 </td>


 </table> 
</center>

<!-- GRAPH SPACE //-->
 <p><div class="graph"><center>GRAPHICAL REPRESENTATION</center></div></p>




</body>



<hr/>
<center><style=padding:100px;>



<!-- FOOTER //-->
<footer>
<div id="donotremove">
    <abbr title="License Availability (v1 on 32)">License Availability</abbr> © 2011-2351  All rights reserved.</a>.</div></footer>
</center>



</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class LicenseServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.print("<html><body><table>");

        // ... pseudocode
        while (resultSet.next()) { 
            out.print("<tr><td>");
            out.print("%8s   %-50s   %-7s%n",resultSet.getString("cymer_id"), resultSet.getString("name"), resultSet.getString("license"));   
            out.print("</td></tr>");

        } 


        out.print("</table></body></html>");
  }
}
```

Comment: @C12-H22-O11 yeah if you can explain how to use this code it will be more helpful...thanks

Comment: You have to deploy the Servlet to your Tomcat. I am not that familiar with Tomcat, but here is a guide for example: http://www.nogoodatcoding.com/howto/deploy-a-servlet-on-tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Create `jsp` file.

See this ***[link](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/display-data-database.shtml)*** for jsp example.

### OR

use `servlet`.

see this ***[link](http://roseindia.net/jsp/servlet-jsp-data-list.shtml)*** for servlet example.

### OR

use `jsf`

See this ***[link](http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/data.shtml)*** for jsf example.

It will help you.

Comment: can you explain me what's the difference between the two methods?

Comment: essentially what are the pros & cons of both the methods..I get how to do that, but I cannot decide which one to use!!

Comment: I tried doing http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/display-data-database.shtml but it cannot connect to the database. My java program can connect from eclipse, do I need to put any additional jar file in tomcat?